# Ansible Equivalent of git remote set-url origin

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to update a git repositories origin with Ansible. The command I'm trying to mimic is `git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here`. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I'm trying to do it without recloning the repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [git_config](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/git_config_module.html#community-general-git-config-read-and-write-git-configuration). For example, given the Git repository *test.git*

```sh
shell> git init --bare  test.git
```

The playbook below does the job

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - git_config:
        repo: 'test.git'
        scope: 'local'
        name: 'remote.origin.url'
        value: 'new.git.url/here'
```

```sh
shell> cd test.git && git config remote.origin.url
new.git.url/here
```